# Remi PHP5/PHP7 repository yum update error

Tags: centos, yum, php

When I run:

```
yum update
```

I get the error:

```
Error: Package: php-pecl-zip-1.20.0-1.el7.remi.5.6.x86_64 (remi-php56)
           Requires: php(api) = 20131106-64
           Installed: php-common-7.4.0~RC1-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (@remi-modular)
               php(api) = 20190902-64
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-48.el7.x86_64 (base)
               php(api) = 20100412-64
           Available: php-common-5.4.45-18.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi)
               php(api) = 20100412-64
           Available: php-common-5.5.38-11.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php55)
               php(api) = 20121113-64
           Available: php-common-5.5.38-12.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php55)
               php(api) = 20121113-64
           Available: php-common-5.6.40-31.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php56)
               php(api) = 20131106-64
           Available: php-common-5.6.40-32.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php56)
               php(api) = 20131106-64
Error: Package: php-pecl-zip-1.20.0-1.el7.remi.5.6.x86_64 (remi-php56)
           Requires: php(zend-abi) = 20131226-64
           Installed: php-common-7.4.0~RC1-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (@remi-modular)
               php(zend-abi) = 20190902-64
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-48.el7.x86_64 (base)
               php(zend-abi) = 20100525-64
           Available: php-common-5.4.45-18.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi)
               php(zend-abi) = 20100525-64
           Available: php-common-5.5.38-11.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php55)
               php(zend-abi) = 20121212-64
           Available: php-common-5.5.38-12.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php55)
               php(zend-abi) = 20121212-64
           Available: php-common-5.6.40-31.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php56)
               php(zend-abi) = 20131226-64
           Available: php-common-5.6.40-32.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php56)
               php(zend-abi) = 20131226-64
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

This is the `yum repolist` output:

```
yum repolist

Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: ftp.plusline.net
 * epel: epel.mirror.far.fi
 * extras: ftp.plusline.net
 * remi: mirror.awanti.com
 * remi-php55: mirror.awanti.com
 * remi-php56: mirror.awanti.com
 * remi-safe: mirror.awanti.com
 * remi-test: mirror.awanti.com
 * updates: de.mirrors.clouvider.net
repo id                                                   repo name                                                                                               status
base/7/x86_64                                             CentOS-7 - Base                                                                                         10,072
docker-ce-stable/7/x86_64                                 Docker CE Stable - x86_64                                                                                  139
epel/x86_64                                               Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64                                                          13,728
extras/7/x86_64                                           CentOS-7 - Extras                                                                                          500
mariadb                                                   MariaDB                                                                                                    101
nginx/x86_64                                              nginx repo                                                                                                 260
nodesource/x86_64                                         Node.js Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64                                                           121
remi                                                      Remi's RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64                                                    7,413
remi-debuginfo/x86_64                                     Remi's RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64 - debuginfo                                        3,494
remi-php55                                                Remi's PHP 5.5 RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64                                              448
remi-php55-debuginfo/x86_64                               Remi's PHP 5.5 RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64 - debuginfo                                  319
remi-php56                                                Remi's PHP 5.6 RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64                                              452
remi-php56-debuginfo/x86_64                               Remi's PHP 5.6 RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64 - debuginfo                                  321
remi-safe                                                 Safe Remi's RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64                                               4,688
remi-test                                                 Remi's test RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64                                               1,845
remi-test-debuginfo/x86_64                                Remi's test RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64 - debuginfo                                     844
updates/7/x86_64                                          CentOS-7 - Updates                                                                                       3,411
vesta/x86_64                                              Vesta - cmmnt                                                                                               27
repolist: 48,183
```

What can I do?

Comment: Please post output of `yum repolist`.

Comment: @Edward i edit the post

Comment: Thanks. Now, what PHP version do you actually want to run? Because you've got `php-pecl-zip-1.20.0-1.el7.remi.5.6.x86_64` installed (PHP5.6), and along with `php-common-7.4.0~RC1-1.el7.remi.x86_64` (PHP7.4) you get a mismatch. If you want to move to PHP7, you'd have to make a note of all current `php*` packages (`rpm -qa|grep php`), then remove all `php-*` packages, disable the `remi-php55`/`remi-php56` and enable `remi-php74` repo, then reinstall the PHP packages you noted earlier.

Comment: @Edward i want to delete php5, actually i run the command yum remove -y php56*, but i continue with the problem

Comment: @Edward I disable de php56 and enable de php74 repo, run the command yum update and now works, thanks

Comment: Great, glad it worked, I'll make it an answer then.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you've got `php-pecl-zip-1.20.0-1.el7.remi.5.6.x86_64` installed (which is part of PHP5.6) and along with `php-common-7.4.0~RC1-1.el7.remi.x86_64` (which is PHP7.4) you get a mismatch.

If you want to move to PHP7.4:

- first make a note of all current `php*` packages (`rpm -qa | grep php`)
- remove all `php-*` packages
- disable the remi-php55/remi-php56 repositories
- enable the remi-php74 repo

Lastly, reinstall the PHP packages you noted earlier.